# How to get depth data from camera images

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturephotooutput, avdepthdata

I am writing an app to get the depth data and disparity data from pictures taken from the camera. I can get the disparity data but not the depth data it always returns nil. I need to get the depth information
and save it as a jpg

I have tried the below code where user can switch between front and back camera and take pictures then the picture we took will be the process

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var ImageView: UIView!

    var img:UIImage?
    var rgbImage:UIImage?

    var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?
    var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInDualCamera, for: .video, position: .back)
    var frontCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInTrueDepthCamera, for: .video, position: .front)
    var capturePhotoOut : AVCapturePhotoOutput?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if #available(iOS 10.2, *){
            let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInDualCamera, for: .video, position: .back)
            do{
                let input = try  AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice!)
                captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
                captureSession?.addInput(input)
                videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession!)
                videoPreviewLayer?.frame = view.layer.bounds
                ImageView.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)
                captureSession?.startRunning()
            }catch{
                print("error")
            }
        }

        capturePhotoOut = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
        capturePhotoOut?.isHighResolutionCaptureEnabled = true
        captureSession?.sessionPreset = .photo
        captureSession?.addOutput(capturePhotoOut!)
        capturePhotoOut!.isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled = capturePhotoOut!.isDepthDataDeliverySupported
        capturePhotoOut!.isPortraitEffectsMatteDeliveryEnabled = capturePhotoOut!.isPortraitEffectsMatteDeliverySupported
    }


    @IBAction func imageCapture(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let capturePhotoOutput = self.capturePhotoOut else {return}
        let photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
        photoSettings.isAutoStillImageStabilizationEnabled = true
        photoSettings.isHighResolutionPhotoEnabled = true
        photoSettings.isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled = true
        photoSettings.isPortraitEffectsMatteDeliveryEnabled = true
        capturePhotoOut?.capturePhoto(with: photoSettings, delegate: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let vc = segue.destination   as! DepthImageView
        vc.img = img
        vc.rgbImg = rgbImage
    }


extension ViewController : AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate{
    public func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        guard error == nil else{return}
        guard let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() else {return}


        let detailImage = UIImage.init(data: imageData,scale: 1.0)
        rgbImage = detailImage

        let nsData = imageData as NSData
        let ptr = nsData.bytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)

        let cfDataset = CFDataCreate(nil,ptr,imageData.count)


        guard let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(cfDataset!,nil) else {return}

        guard let auxDataInfo = CGImageSourceCopyAuxiliaryDataInfoAtIndex(source, 0, kCGImageAuxiliaryDataTypeDepth) as? [String : AnyObject] else {
            return
        }

        var depthData: AVDepthData

        do {
            depthData = try AVDepthData(fromDictionaryRepresentation: auxDataInfo)

            if depthData.depthDataType != kCVPixelFormatType_DepthFloat32 {
                depthData = depthData.converting(toDepthDataType: kCVPixelFormatType_DepthFloat32)
            }

            let depthDataMap = depthData.depthDataMap

            let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: depthDataMap)

            let depthDataMapImage = UIImage(ciImage: ciImage,scale: 1.0,orientation: .down)
            img = depthDataMapImage
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ImageViewScreen", sender: self)

        } catch {
            print("Error")
        }
    }
}
```

I always get nil at auxDataInfo guard

Answer (score 1):

AVCapturePhoto containing information about AVDepthData. Try to get depth Data from photo

```
let depthData = photo.depthData
```